# How to I set one root application next to other applications on Oracle Weblogic Server?

Tags: java, oracle, weblogic

I got 3 applications running on my Weblogic server. Let's say these are:

- www.example.org/a
- www.example.org/b
- www.example.org/c

Now I want application "a" to be directly available via www.example.org **without the /a at the end**.

I know that I can set context-root for "a" like this:

```
   <web>
      <web-uri>a.war</web-uri>
      <context-root>/</context-root>
   </web>
```

But won't this cause any problems with the other installed apps like path collisions and such?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use Oracle HTTP Server, Apache Web Server (with WebLogic plugin), or Oracle Traffic Director, to correctly map that, instead of deploying an application to root context.

Keep all apps deployed to their / context roots. Map the external context root on the Web Tier.

Comment: We're using NGINX Web Server, do you know if that'd work as well?

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you must use Nginx in front o WebLogic? Why not use OHS (which is already included in your license, with support) ?